# Is there any wired headphones solution to make calls while charging iPhone 7?

Tags: audio, call, lightning, iphone

There are lots of hardware to listen to music while charging iPhone 7 but is there any way to make calls and charge iPhone 7 at the same time?

1. Using a lightning headset?
2. Using a 3.5 mm headset?

Comment: A [bluetooth to 3.5mm](https://griffintechnology.com/us/holiday/stocking-stuffers-2016/itrip-clip-bluetooth-headphone-adapter) device may work. I'm getting one of the linked Griffin Technologies iTrip adaptors in a few days. It touts: **Built-in handsfree mic is perfect for video and audio calling.** I haven't used it yet, obviously, so I won't put this as an official answer. It should work, but I have no personal experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first scenario, [this article](https://www.google.cl/amp/amp.imore.com/how-charge-your-iphone-7-and-listen-headphones-same-time) covers some options. The first one is this charge and listen device:

[Belkin Lightning Audio + Charge RockStar](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F8J198/)

[image: Belkin Lightning Audio + Charge RockStar]

Comment: This Belkin solution works great (and I believe is currently sold exclusively by Apple only) - while the industrial design is clunky and disappointing it does the job nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Apple's official [iPhone Lightning Dock](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MGRM2AM/A/iphone-lightning-dock-white).

It has a TRRS connector which supports audio output as well as audio input (for microphone-equipped headsets).

[image]